# Getting nil response while passing string to another view controller - Swift3

Tags: swift3

In FirstViewController i'm fetching the response from JSON and want to pass that fetched response to another view controller.Below is the code which i have used so far for parsing and passing the response.

**FirstViewController**

```
var fn:String!  //globally declared variable
```

code i have tried for parsing in FirstViewController

```
 do {

    let detailsDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> as NSDictionary


    print(detailsDictionary)
    let details = detailsDictionary["Data"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    print(details)
    for dtl in details
    {
        self.fn = dtl["Father_Name"] as? String ?? "NA"
        print(self.fn)  //here i'm getting the exact value from JSON        
     }

    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**

In SecondViewController there is a Label called profile_name and want to set that parsed string(**fn**) as Label's text. for that i declared another variable as global.

```
var pname:String!
```

below is the code i have used to fetch the value from FirstViewController.

```
viewDidLoad()
{
       let othervc = FirstViewController()
       self.pname = othervc.fn
       self.profile_name.text = self.pname
}
```

**Problem : I tried my best efforts to get the desired output but i'm getting nil response.**

Please Help.

Comment: Is your "profile_name" Label connected as outlet? Because if you get this error: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", probably your outlet is not connected.

Comment: outlet is connected.

Comment: Please only show _relevant_ code in your question. For example, why do you think the contents of your `heightForRowAt` will help people solve your problem?

Comment: Most likely the cause of the issue is `FirstViewController()`. The default initializer creates a new instance which is not the instance designed in the storyboard. In this new instance `fn` is `nil`. You have to get the proper instance in the view hierarchy, either with outlet, callback closure, protocol/delegate or notification.

Answer (score 0):

**In Second ViewController**

```
let strName:String!
```

**In First ViewController**

```
let strOne = "This is for testing"

let objstory = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yout Secoond ViewController Storybord ID") as! YourSecondViewControllerName
objstory.strNam = strOne     

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objstory, animated: true)
```

Comment: i tried your code but still m not able to set up label's text. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: try to set  yourlableName.text = strName   in viewdid load method of second ViewController

Comment: have already set up in viewDidLoad :(. not getting any error but still label is empty :(.

Comment: i have updated my question with secondviewcontroller. not label's value m passing fn to another view controller's label text. check the code in firstviewcontroller from this line operationqueue.main.addoperation.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code just won't work.

```
let othervc = FirstViewController()
```

creates a **new instance** of `FirstViewController` (not the one that got the JSON).

You should be handling it something like this:

In `FirstViewController`

```
let fn = dtl["Father_Name"] as? String ?? "NA"
let svc = SecondViewController() // Or maybe instantiate from Storyboard, or maybe you already have a reference to it
svc.pname = fn
present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then in `SecondViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profile_name.text = pname
}
```

I'd suggest you take some time out and re-read [Apple's View Controller programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS).

---

*Original Answer*

The problem you have here…

```
vcvalue.profile_name.text = fn
```

is that `profile_name` is `nil` as the view for the view controller hasn't been loaded at this point.

You should handle this by creating a property in `LeftSideMenuViewController`

```
var name: String?
```

Then set

```
vcvalue.name = fn
```

And then in `LeftSideMenuViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profile_name.text = name
}
```

Also, some basic tips…

- Don't force unwrap (!) apart from IBOutlets. You may have to write a bit more code, but you will reduce crashes.
- Make `@IBOutlet`s `private` - this will prevent you accidentally assigning to them as you are now
- If you're overriding any `viewWill/DidDis/Appear` methods, you must call `super` at some point.
- You need to re-read the section on `switch/case`

So this…

```
let  a = indexPath.row
switch(a)
    {
    case 0 :
        if(a == 0)
        {
            return 45
        }
        break
     etc
```

could just be…

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0...4:
    return 45
case 5:
    return 50
default: 
    break
}
```

Comment: sir you mean to say instantiateviewcontroller and other stuff is not required?

Comment: No, just do the same as you're doing, but don't assign to the outlet from the first view controller (in fact, make all your IBOutlets private to prevent this)

Comment: sir still i'm not able to get desired output :(.

Comment: sir i followed same steps but in LeftSideMenuViewController m getting nil value . sir plz guide me dont knw wht m missing. and one more thing i would like to share with you is that i put this profile_name.text = pname in dispatchqueue.main.async block in viewWillappear method.

Comment: OK - Before you do anything, please read [mcve] and [ask]. *When you've done that*, edit your question and show your current code and **remove all irrelevant code**. Also, please show some respect by not using abbreviations like "knw wht m " in comments.

Comment: I updated my question.Thank you sir for your guidance on how to ask a question.It would be great if you will help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Sir I am getting an error : Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit at this line : present(svc,animated:true,completion:nil)

Comment: OK, I can't help you with every line of code. You need to go back to basics. Read Apple's documentation and work through their example code.

Comment: i am sorry to say you sir but i dont think this is the right way to reply i came back to you with error because you answered to my question.Thank you so much.